# How do I compare each number from an array starting from the right hand side?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble figuring out how to compare two different sets of numbers in an array. They have to be in exact order from the right-hand side in order to get points. For example: If the 1st set is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` and the 2nd set is `1 2 4 3 2 6 7` then you get two points as the last two digits match but stops at the 3rd one so the rest isn't counted. That is what I've got so far, it's part of an even bigger set of code about Lottos.

```
private static Random rndNumbers = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] extraPlayMax = ChangeLottoEXTRA1();
        PlayLottoMAX(extraPlayMax);
    }
    static int[] ChangeLottoEXTRA1()
    {
        int[] lottoExtraArray = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < lottoExtraArray.Length; i++)
        {
            lottoExtraArray[i] = rndNumbers.Next(1, 10);
        }
        return lottoExtraArray;
    }
    static void PlayLottoMAX(int[] extraArray)
    {
        int countExtra = 0;
        Console.Write("The current Lotto EXTRA number is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < extraArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{extraArray[i]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Your Lotto EXTRA number is: ");
        int[] yourExtra = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < extraArray.Length; i++)
        {
            yourExtra[i] = rndNumbers.Next(1, 10);
            Console.Write($"{yourExtra[i]}");
            if (extraArray[i] == yourExtra[i])
            {
                countExtra++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Your Lotto EXTRA Match: {countExtra}/7");
    }
```

Comment: You haven't explained your problem, just your intention. The *Problem* in this case is the logic part you don't understand. After going over this with the step debugger, you should have a great understanding of where this going wrong, and should easily be able to explain which line it is, whats happening, and your intended results.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've just been working on this for hours now and should just take a break and go through everything step by step again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok excepting the last `for` loop.

You will have to exit the loop when you find 2 different numbers. You can do like this:

```
        if (extraArray[i] == yourExtra[i])
        {
            countExtra++;
        } else 
          break;
```

Comment: that was close thanks, I ended up adding a little more to get what I want. `while (extraCheck)
                {
                    if (extraArray[i] == yourExtra[i])
                    {
                        countExtra++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        extraCheck = false;
                        break;
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone will care but all I needed was to the bottom part of the code to this. Now I just need to figure out how to reverse it. Thanks everyone!

```
for (int i = 0; i < extraArray.Length; i++)
        {
            yourExtra[i] = rndNumbers.Next(1, 10);
            Console.Write($"{yourExtra[i]}");
            while (extraCheck)
            {
                if (extraArray[i] == yourExtra[i])
                {
                    countExtra++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    extraCheck = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not `for(int i=extraArray.Length-1; i>=0; i--)` instead?